# I cannot send email in Laradock environment

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, dockerfile, mail-server, laradock

So, I use `Laradock` for my PHP project development environment. I have issue when send email to mailtrap and have this error:

`sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found`

How to solve this? **or is there any alternative to mail testing in Laradock the best practice and ways?**

I already try to install sendmail in php-fpm dockerfile `apt-get install -y sendmail && \`, and then re-build the container, seems the sendmail is installed as seen in the log, then restart the container, it still has same error:

`sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found`

my php-fpm/Dockerfile

```
...

# always run apt update when start and after add new source list, then clean up at end.
RUN set -xe; \
    apt-get install -y sendmail && \
    apt-get update -yqq && \
    pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && \
    apt-get install -yqq \
      apt-utils \
      #
      #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # Mandatory Software's Installation
      #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      #
      # Mandatory Software's such as ("mcrypt", "pdo_mysql", "libssl-dev", ....)
      # are installed on the base image 'laradock/php-fpm' image. If you want
      # to add more Software's or remove existing one, you need to edit the
      # base image (https://github.com/Laradock/php-fpm).
      #
      # next lines are here becase there is no auto build on dockerhub see https://github.com/laradock/laradock/pull/1903#issuecomment-463142846
      libzip-dev zip unzip && \
      docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip && \
      # Install the zip extension
      docker-php-ext-install zip && \


      php -m | grep -q 'zip'

...
```

I expect the mail sent to my mailtrap, It's once succeed when I used Wampserver

Comment: Why don't you want to use mailu instead? It's out of box in the docker-compose.yml .

Comment: I tried to run the `mailu` container, it gave me `ERROR: for mailu-front  Cannot start service mailu-front: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint laradock_mailu-front_1 (a7043bb9c875238e72b94b3570ee01fab27b99a8a90995530f2717108520626b): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:25 failed: port is already allocated` how to solve this?

Comment: check which service uses 25 port on your main server. docker ps can show you all ports which are used by docker. Otherwise you can find how to check the rest one here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/

Comment: never mind about this. I'm using mailhog now. It's more simple if you know the settings. I have created the post how to use it at https://dev.to/dendihandian/mailhog-in-laradock-1ej6